# PHP: как преобразовать строку с hex в обычный hex?

Tags: php, hex, range

Есть задача вывести алфавит на разных языках, в базе есть hex код первого и последнего символа алфавита.

пример кода:

```
$first = '0xC0';
$last = '0xDF';
foreach (range(chr($first), chr($last)) as $b){
            $abc[] = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $b);
}
```

как строку '0xC0' преобразовать в 0xC0?

Comment: если 0x отрезать то hex2bin даст готовый символ с этим кодом, например

Comment: ну или base_convert(x, 16, 10) он вроде и 0x в начале норм проглатывает

Comment: спасибо тебе, добрый человек!!! вариант с base_convert(x, 16, 10) работает